# Accessing Variable inside Inner Class

Tags: java, android, maps, inner-classes

I have a listener and I want to access variable outside the listener method. But even after initializing the variable globally its showing "0" outside scope.

Can anyone explain the reason

```
public class MapsActivity{
   double origin_lat;
   //
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       //
       srcLat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            double value = (double) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            origin_lat=value;  -- > value shows here
            Log.d("SourceLatitude",Double.toString(value));

        }
       });
   Log.d("OutsideScope",Double.toString(origin_lat)); -- > shows "0"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a listener and I want to access variable outside the listener
>   method. But even after initializing the variable globally its showing
>   "0" outside scope.
>
> Can anyone explain the reason

because `onMapReady/onDataChange` is/are `async` and not `sync` as you think. Android calls it their initialization, in the first case and when the new data is available in the second case. The purpose of having them async is to avoid to block the UI Thread in case of heavy computation, leaving your users the possibility to interact with the UI

Comment: So anyway I can access that value ??

Comment: of course you can. You are already accessing it `Log.d("SourceLatitude",Double.toString(value));`, aren't you?

Comment: @Mr.A.N: You could send an intent when the value changes

Comment: it does show 0 on `Log.d("OutsideScope",D`, right ?

Comment: Yes I want to access outside scope .. and ir shows 0 there

Comment: @fabian can you try to give some code sample I'm newbie

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself familiar with intents. Intents are something very basic in android applications.
Here is the docu: [Android Docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

You would then send an intent to your activity.
In the activity you woul register a receiver, that uses the value of the intent.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are telling the app to do:

1. When Map is ready, add a `ListenerForSingleValueEvent` to `srcLat` and print the current value of `origin_lat`
2. From now on, when data changes (`onDataChange` is called on that newly added listener), you want to change the value of `origin_lat` and print that.

Note that in step 1, the value of `origin_lat` has not (necessarily) yet been modified by `onDataChange` because `onDataChange` has not been called yet. Once that happens,  `origin_lat` will change.

As Blackbelt says, you seem to  think the code runs sequentially because it is written sequentially. Buy you added an async listener of some sort, and that will run whenever it wants.